# How to test custom JsonSerializer with JUnit and Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

i have a custom JsonSerialzier to serialize dates in a special format:

```
public class CustomDateJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider arg2) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String outputDateValue;
        //... do something with the Date and write the result into outputDateValue
        gen.writeString(outputDateValue);
    }
}
```

It works fine but how can i test my code with JUnit and Mockito? Or rather how can i mock the JsonGenerator and access the result?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possibly in this case you won't want to mock the Json generator (Jackson?), but just use it.

Comment: I tried to mock JsonGenerator (Jackson!). But how to handle the void method writeString(String s)?

Comment: You can simply mock the `JsonGenerator` and verify that is has called the writeString method with the expected `outputDateValue`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CustomDateJsonSerializerTest {

    @Mock
    private JsonGenerator gen;

    @Test
    public void testOutputDateValue() {
        CustomDateJsonSerializer serializer = new CustomDateJsonSerializer();
        serializer.serialize(new Date(), gen, null /*or whatever it needs to be*/);

        String expectedOutput = "whatever the correct output should be";
        verify(gen, times(1)).writeString(expectedOutput);
    }

}
```